# Do transparent electronic paper displays exist as a commercial product?

Tags: e-ink

Is there a such thing as a transparent [electronic paper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_paper) display that is commercially available ?

I've found that Samsung has a [transparent LCD](http://www.samsung.com/us/business/oem-solutions/lcdpanels/transparent-lcd-panels.html), but I haven't been able to find any examples of transparent e-paper.

Comment: I don't think you're going to find such a thing. All of the e-paper technologies I'm aware of intentionally use *opaque* white/black particles to produce their images. They're implicitly reflective, not transmissive, displays.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not likely. E-ink consists of an array of tiny balls between two two electrode sheets.

[image]

[source](http://www.eink.com/technology.html)

A positive or negative electric field makes that either black or white pigment chips will be at the viewing side. If those were transparent you would see the inactive white chips through the black ones and vice versa, and have no contrast.

There's an illuminated Kindle, the Paperwhite, but that has front-lighting, not back-lighting:

[image]

[source](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007OZNZG0)

Comment: wow ! Need to give +100 for info.

Comment: What if instead of using the titanium dioxide particles (the white pigment), glass was used. Would that make the displays transparent ? I suppose the bottom electrode would have to be made transparent also.

Comment: @Walter - No that wouldn't work. If you would look through a black pixels and its inverse below you would see the same as looking through a white pixel and its inverse below; there won't be any difference between black and white. The pigment chips have to be opaque to prevent you from seeing the inverse color underneath it. Also, if you would see what's behind the display, how can you see the display itself? Head-up displays works because their image is projected on *the front* of the glass. The projector needs a high light level and high contrast.

Comment: @stevenvh great point. I think this completes my understanding of why e-paper displays are all front-lit.

Comment: The question asked about e-paper, not e-ink.  Epaper displays use a wide range of technology.  E-ink is a single trademarked technology.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, displays based on PDLC have been developed for reflective/transparent mode operation.  For this to work, your pixel layer has to achieve a nice diffuse state (traditional LCD does not).

Comment: From my understanding, require a constant voltage to remain in the transparent state (and is opaque with no voltage). e-paper only requires voltage to switch states, but not to remain in a given state.

Comment: @Jason - Walter asked specifically about e-paper/e-ink. PDLC is an LCD technology.

Answer (score 1):

Cholesteric Lcd can be the option, it's optical perneteation >25%
http://www.iris-opt.com/index.php?lang=en

Comment: Can you expand this answer?